# How to find tight bound for $\Theta(n\cdot \lg n\cdot\lg\frac{n}{\lg n})$?

Tags: asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

I need to find tight bound for $\Theta\big(n\cdot \lg n\cdot\lg\frac{n}{\lg n}\big)$, ($\Theta$) bound specifically.

I thought doing a limit: 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{\lg n}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{1\over n}=\infty\implies\lg n=o(n)\implies\\\Theta\bigg(n\cdot \lg n\cdot\lg\frac{n}{\lg n}\bigg)=O(n\lg^2 n)
$$

So I can get only an upper bound. In addition I wonder if there's a simpler way to do this because of logarithmic identity:
$$
\Theta\bigg(n\cdot \lg n\cdot\lg\frac{n}{\lg n}\bigg)=\Theta(n\cdot \lg n\cdot(\lg n-\lg(\lg n)))
$$
but I don't know how to go about the minus when determining a bound.

Comment: Do you mind adding parentheses to the main expression? Unclear if you mean $\lg (n \lg \frac{n}{\lg n})$ or $(\lg n) (\lg \frac{n}{\lg n})$ Based on the middle of your post I am guessing it is the latter.

Comment: @angryavian good call, I added multiplication signs